# Installing IBM HTTP Server?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

My team is trying to figure out how to install IBM HTTP Server for Websphere V8.5.5, and we can't use IHS V9 (I've been told it does not work). The only option available is to use installation manager. I've gotten the lastest installation manager (or the right version really) and am able to point it at repositories mentioned, but packages are missing!

OS: Linux 32-bit

IBM Websphere v8.5.5

---

Commands I've tried and the errors I get:

```
./imcl -prompt install com.ibm.websphere.IHS.v85_8.5.5014.20180802_1018 -repositories http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/com.ibm.websphere.IHSILAN.v85 -acceptLicense -showProgress -properties user.ihs.httpPort=80
```

`ERROR: 'zip com.ibm.websphere.IHS.msl_001_all.all 8.5.0.201205011534' not found.`

```
./imcl -prompt install com.ibm.websphere.IHS.v85_8.5.5014.20180802_1018 -repositories https://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/V85WASDeveloperILAN,https://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/V85WASSupplementsILAN -acceptLicense -showProgress -properties user.ihs.httpPort=80
```

`ERROR: zip com.ibm.websphere.IHS.msl_001_all.all 8.5.0.201205011534 not found`

---

I have also tried downloading WAS Supplements Fix Pack 12 and 14 for Distributed OS, and some of the other packages in those fix packs, and I get similar errors:

`CRIMC1020E ERROR:   file com.ibm.websphere.IHS.ihsonly_014_unixDist.all_x_8.5.0.201205011604 not found`

`CRIMC1020E ERROR:   zip com.ibm.websphere.IHS.ihsonly.32bit_006_unixDist.all_x 8.5.0.201205011603 not found`

`CRIMC1020E ERROR:   zip com.ibm.websphere.IHS.msl_001_all.all 8.5.0.201205011534 not found`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pointed at the ILAN (trial, unsupported, etc) "composite repository" (alias?) but tried to install the non-ILAN (licensed) offering.   In 8.5.5 at least, all of the supplements have one offering that is available ILAN w/o any entitlement.

The error message you get is a roundabout way of telling you that the few original sub-packages (the "2012" is the hint) that are restricted to entitled users are not in a repo you can reach.

In other words s/com.ibm.websphere.IHS.v85_8.5.5014.20180802_1018/com.ibm.websphere.IHSILAN.v85_8.5.5014.20180802_1018 in your command line invocation. Or, point at a repo that is not limited to free/unwarranted/ILAN downloads.

Comment: I am trying to get the "free" ones. These repos with listAvailablePackages say they have some sort of IHS offering. So I want the "ILAN" versions?

Comment: Yes, you will see IHSILAN offerings

Comment: This worked. I am really really grateful for your quick response! Many of the websphere questions go unanswered!

Comment: only problem i see now is `./httpd: error while loading shared libraries: libaprutil-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` ... but maybe thats b/c i uninstalled websphere before i installed IHS. Hopefully this is just a common library... Yeah that was fixed easily by `sudo apt-get install libaprutil1`. now it works!! thx!!!

Comment: No, use "apachectl" not "httpd".